# Dark keyboard changes to light on dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c

I set a textfield's keyboard appearance to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` and it shows up fine, but when the keyboard gets dismissed it flashes back to the light appearance during the dismiss animation. It's pretty distracting, and I can't figure out how to get it to stay dark during the dismiss animation. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I'm not seeing this on either device or simulator. When/where are you setting the appearance to dark? Also, what iOS version are you on?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing it on other apps either. I'm setting it in `viewDidLoad`, and I'm on 7.1.1.

Comment: Do you maybe have other text fields in the view/controller with light keyboards? I'm not seeing any reason that the system would switch it unless you're either telling it to, or setting a default appearance somewhere maybe. Have you tried a clean/build or uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Only the one textfield in that controller (though I'm seeing it with every textfield in the app), but there's no default appearance set. Also just tried a clean and a reinstall, still seeing the same thing. So weird.

Comment: Did you try to set it up in Xcode? https://www.dropbox.com/s/gacnh5ch1ezynr8/Screenshot%202014-07-17%2022.17.40.png

Comment: Yep, I tried setting it in Interface Builder as well. And I even tried setting a default appearance for the keyboard in the app delegate.

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? Facing the same issues years later